# Is the integral functional $I(x) = \int_{0}^{T} \Lambda (t , x(t), \dot{x} (t)) \; dt $ lipschitz around $x_0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, optimal-control

Let the function $\Lambda : [0,T] \times \mathbb{R^n} \times \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb R$ be continuously differentiable. Assume the integral functional $I(x) = \int_{0}^{T} \Lambda (t , x(t), \dot{x} (t)) \; dt $ is finite value for all $x \in AC[0,T]$ on a neighborhood of $x_0$.

My question:  Is the integral functional $I(x) = \int_{0}^{T} \Lambda (t , x(t), \dot{x} (t)) \; dt $ lipschitz on a neighborhood of $x_0$ ?

P.S:  $AC[0, T]$ stands for the space of all absolutely continuous function $x: [0,T] \to \mathbb R^n$ equipped with $W^{1,1}$ norm which is $$   \| x \| := \int_{0}^{T} \|x(t)\| \; dt + \int_{0}^{T} \|x'  (t)\| \; dt$$

Comment: Sure, it is....

Comment: @amsmath could you please provide a proof or at least a hint ?

Comment: I might have been too fast. You might get a problem when $x_0'$ is unbounded.

Comment: @amsmath Exactly. But the assumption of $I(x)$ being finite might help.

Comment: The integral for example exists when $\Lambda$ is bounded. But $\Lambda$ might be bounded with $\Lambda'(t,x,y)$ being large for $y$ far out.

Comment: @amsmath  Thanks. Can you think about a sufficient condition that makes result correct ? Clearly If $\Lambda$ be Lipschitz then it is correct. But I'm looking for a local condition .

Comment: $\Lambda$ should be measurable in $t$, locally Lipschitz in $x$, and globally Lipschitz in $y$.

Comment: @HansEngler Thanks.  We can already $\Lambda$ is continuously differentiable.  So I think I need just think about assumption on the argument $y$. When  you say lipschitz in y, does the constant lipschitz is uniform in $(t ,x)$ ?

Comment: The Lipschitz constant could depend on $x$ but not on $t$ (I think).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **no**.

Consider the case  $AC([0,1])$ and $\Lambda(t,x,y) = y\sin (y)$. This function is $C^\infty$. Set $x_n(t) = nt$ on $[0,n^{-1}]$ and $1$ for $x > n^{-1}$. These functions are uniformly bounded in $AC$.

Then $\|x_n - x_{n+1}\|_{AC} = O(n^{-1})$. But $I(x_n) = \sin n$. Clearly there is no finite Lipschitz constant.

Comment: $$  | I(x) - I(y) | = |  \int_{0}^{T} \sin x'(t)  - \sin y'(t) | \leq \int_{0}^{T} |x' (t) - y'(t)| \leq \|  x - y \| $$

So it is Lipschitz !

Comment: Whoops, you are right. There was a typo, which is now fixed.

Comment: Thank you. Just one question, what is $x_0$ here ? It seems the sequence $x_n$ does not converge to any point in $AC[0,1]$, because if it does it has to converge to $x=1$, and clearly this convergent is not uniform so it is not in $W^{1,1}$ norm !

Comment: I'm not sure if you got my point. My question is about local Lipschitzian but your answer only rejects entire Lipschitzian .

Comment: @Redshoes You can choose $x_0=0$. Then the $x_n$ are in a neighborhood of $x_0$ (we have $\|x_n\|_{AC} = 2-\frac 1{2n}$) and for any $x\in AC[0,1]$ with $\|x\|_{AC}\le C$ we have $\Lambda(t,x(t),\dot x(t))\in L^1(0,1)$. However, the $x_n$ don't approach any function in $AC[0,1]$. So, if your question is *Is there a neighborhood of $x_0$*, then this is not a valid counterexample.

Comment: @amsmath yes, that's  the my question

Comment: @Redshoes - my answer can be modified to show that $I$ is not Lipschitz continuous on any neighborhood of $x_0 = 0$  in $AC$. Given any $\varepsilon$ ball about $x_0$, multiply the sequence given in the answer by $\varepsilon$. This is a sequence inside the ball. Convergence to any particular point in the neighborhood does not follow and is not required for the argument. After all, this is an infinite-dimensional space.